# Find whether the function is bounded.

Tags: calculus, functions

The problem is to figure out whether this function is bounded:
$\frac{5\sqrt{a}}{1+4\sqrt{a}}$

I've already figured out that it's bounded from below but I'm not sure about the upper bound. I know that square root function in general doesn't have an upper bound but I think, the function I was given is upper bounded.

I tried plugging the whole function into the: $|f(x)|\le M$ and I did get that $()$ is definitely less than 5. Which works just fine (we've been told at school that the value of M doesn't have to be smallest value unless it says so in the problem). But I'm having doubts after seeing the graph of the function. It keeps increasing but doesn't seem to surpass $2$.

Comment: There are two cases, one is 1 is greater than $\sqrt{a}$ or the other way, you can compute the bound for each case.

Comment: You can also divide numerator and denomenator by $\sqrt{a}$ to get a more understandable function - then look at the range for denominator and invert.

Comment: @Yimin, why, though? $f(x):=\frac5{\frac1{\sqrt x}+4}$ if $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0.$

Comment: I tried plugging the whole function into the: $\left | f(x) \right | \leq M$ and I did get that $f(x)$ is definitely less than $5$. Which works just fine (we've been told at school that the value of M doesn't have to be smallest value unless it says so in the problem). But I'm having doubts after seeing the graph of the function. It keeps increasing but doesn't seem to surpass 2.

Comment: @Invisible you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{{5\sqrt a }}{{1 + 4\sqrt a }} = \frac{5}{4}\frac{{4\sqrt a }}{{1 + 4\sqrt a }} = \frac{5}{4}\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{1 + 4\sqrt a }}} \right) \le \frac{5}{4}
$$
for all $a\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>0$, we have $$4+\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\ge 4$$

Hence we have $$\frac{1}{4+\frac1{\sqrt{x}} }\le \frac14 $$

Multiply by $5$ would give you an upperbound.

Answer (score 0):

As $a$ goes to infinity, $5\sqrt{a}\over 1+4\sqrt{a}$ goes to $5\over 4$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. There is $a_0>0$ such that $\forall a\ge a_0$, $|{5\sqrt{a}\over 1+4\sqrt{a}}-{5\over 4}|<\epsilon$. $5\sqrt{a}\over 1+4\sqrt{a}$ is clearly bounded on $[0,a_0]$, and also bounded on $[a_0,\infty]$, so it is bounded over $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: So it is bounded from below but there is no upper bound, yeah?

Comment: @Ivka Have you checked the other two answers? $5/4$ is an upper bound and is the best upper bound.

Comment: I have, I guess I'm just a bit lost in here. First time user.

Comment: @runtotherescue Now that you have received 3 different answers check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @runtotherescue, your function has a horizontal [asymptote](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote).

Comment: Thank you for help, lads